# Removing Div from Website only works the first time

Tags: javascript, html, mutation-observers, mutation

I am trying to build an chrome extension for lichess.org to permanently remove some elements from the website.

As the elements (in this case divs) can reappear if the user navigates through the website, I implemented a MutationObserver to remove the divs again as soon as they get added again. However, even though the function to remove them is called and they don't change their data-id, they are only removed when the function is called for the first time.

This is what I've tried so far:

These are the divs I want to remove. They are exactly the same after reappearing.

```
const bullet1 = document.querySelector('[data-id="1+0"]');
const bullet2 = document.querySelector('[data-id="2+1"]');
```

This is the MutationObserver. The div gets added with the addedNode.

```
const parent_lobby = document.querySelector("#main-wrap > main");

const mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
   
    if (mutations[0].addedNodes[0].className == "lobby__app lobby__app-pools"){
        remove_bullet_QP();
    }
})

mutationObserver.observe(parent_lobby, {childList: true})
```

This is the function called to remove the elements. The first call of the method that happens as soon a the webiste is opened.

```
function remove_bullet_QP(){
    bullet1.remove();
    bullet2.remove();
}

remove_bullet_QP();
```

I've also tried to overwrite the divs before calling the function to remove them, but it didn't change the result.

Comment: My guess is `parent_lobby` is removed and added as a new element. Hard to guess.

Comment: Re-select those queries on every func call?

Comment: have you made sure the mutation observer is actually being triggered in that if statement when they reappear? with a console.log? Cause the code to remove the elements is fine and repeatable, I would guess that function is just never actually triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help.

I changed bullet1 and bullet2 from const to let and reassigned them in every function call. This seems to work.

As I've said in my question, I've tried reassigning before, but without changing it to let. This should have given me an error message, somehow it didn't.

Comment: Better yet, keep them `const` and query them in the function directly. `let` and global state are harder to reason about.